# How it works to give a number and return a string after adding in Javascript

Tags: javascript, recursion

This function take a number as an input and return a string with sum. How actually its working

```
findSolution(21);
// returns:
((((1 + 5)  + 5)  + 5)  + 5)
```

```js
function findSolution(target) {
  function find(start, history) {

    if (start == target)
      return history;
    else if (start > target)
      return null;
    else
      return find(start + 5, "(" + history + " + 5) ") ||
             find(start * 3, "(" + history + " * 3) ");
  }
  return find(1, "1");
}
console.log(findSolution(21));
```

Comment: If the intent of the function is to find an expression that equals the given target, it doesn't work.  For many inputs it finds no valid expression.

Comment: Your (now edited) statement was contradictory.  It originally said you were "advanced" in those subjects, when anyone who actually was would have no problem understanding this code.

Comment: If you are a beginner trying to understand how a recursive function works, in my opinion the best way is to use pencil and paper to manually work through an example that doesn't recurse too deep. Pretend you are the JS interpreter, and write down the values of the variables when the `find()` is first called, then note if it would do the if, the else if, or the else case, then if it comes to the else and calls itself make a note of what value it has passed as an argument on another line on your page, etc. (Or add a whole lot of `console.log()` statements within the function.)

Comment: @Badrkhan no, he's talking about understanding recursion.

Comment: It is _completely inappropriate_ to utterly change your question to one that isn't remotely related.  You should have opened a new question.   I have rolled back the question to the previous version accordingly.   I'd quite like the "accept" vote back, too!

Comment: But that was basic question and I was getting down votes.

Comment: Why people are giving me down votes for this basic question :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a (simple) recursive pattern.

The inner function either:

- finds that the target has been found, and returns it
- or finds that the target has been exceeded, when it returns `null`
- otherwise tries to call itself with either `(n + 5)` or `(n * 3)`, accumulating the output from the previous stage as it goes.

The first two options are the ones that terminate the recursion.

The `||` operator is the important part of third case.  It first tries the `n + 5` solution, but only if that recursive call returns `null` will the lazy `||` operator evaluate the `n * 3` call.

Note however that if *both* calls fail because `n * 3` and `n + 5` both exceed the target value (which they do, for lots of numbers) then the whole function will return `null`.

Comment: The `history` argument is the actual expression that it's trying to build.  It gets progressively longer as the recursion continues.  Put a simple `console.log(start, history)` in the first line of the `find()` functoin as @nnnnnnn suggested and you should see the call flow.

Comment: Well, yes, and wraps the parentheses around it too.

Comment: That's just the call to start the inner function with the initial parameters